# SNOWFLAKE SQL: How to run several select statement in one command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am a newbie in the SQL world, and hoping SMEs in the community can help me.

**What I am trying to solve for**: Several 'select' statement  to run on a weekly basis with one call, and the results gets download to on my computer (bonus if it can be downloaded on specific folder)
**How I am doing it right now**: I use SNOWFLAKE (that's the approved software we are using), Run each 'select' statement one at a time, then once each result is displayed, I manually download the csv file on my computer

I know there's an efficient way of doing it, so would appreciate the help from this community.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend scripting this out in a batch script and execute using SnowSQL (a command-line tools for Snowflake), which will also allow you to extract the data and `GET` it back onto your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple queries at once using [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) Client. Here's how

**Preparation:**

1. Setup SnowSLQL connection configuration

- open file: `.snowsql/config`
- add your connection details:

```
[connections.my_sample_connection]
accountname = mysnowflakeaccount
username = myusername
password = mypassword
warehousename = mywarehouse
```

2. Create your query file.
   e.g. `my_query.sql`

```
-- Query 1
select 1 col1, 2 col2;

-- Query 2
select 'a' colA, 'b' colB;
```

**Execution:**

```
snowsql -c my_sample_connection -f my_query.sql -o output_file=/path/query_result.csv -o timing=false -o friendly=false -o output_format=csv
```

**Result:**
`/path/query_result.csv` - Containing the result of the queries in `my_query.sql`